# Count specific keys

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have this object:

```
"formData": {
    "Total": "60.00",
    "listTable": [],
    "tr0_CC": "KFC",
    "tr0_amount": "10.00",
    "tr1_CC": "SUB",
    "tr1_amount": "20.00",
    "tr2_CC": "WEN",
    "tr2_amount": "30.00"
}
```

How can I count only keys `tr#_amount` with either native or lodash? In example above I should get `3`.

Comment: Let's see, I see three keys that match tr#_amount. They are tr0_amount, tr1_amount, and tr2_amount. One, two, three, ah ah ah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some standard (ES6) Javascript:

```js
a = {"formData": {
    "Total": "60.00",
    "listTable": [],
    "tr0_CC": "KFC",
    "tr0_amount": "10.00",
    "tr1_CC": "SUB",
    "tr1_amount": "20.00",
    "tr2_CC": "WEN",
    "tr2_amount": "30.00"
}};

console.log(Object.keys(a.formData).filter(t => t.match(/tr\d+_amount/)).length);
```